# Finding the limit as $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: Problem]
I was shown the above problem in my calculus class today.  It seems that one can solve the limit in white by realizing that it mirrors the limit in yellow.

However, I don't understand what the exact relationship between those two limits is. My TA went over it rather quickly. Can someone explain what point he was trying to make?

Comment: I would use the rules of L'Hospital

Comment: I would read the question and then suggest something

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Fascinating. That would lead to a very good answer with a very good number of downvotes, at it'd essentially miss entirely the point of the question.

Answer (score 5):

$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$

Take $x_0=0$ and $f(x)=\cos{(1+\ln{(x^2+1)})}$

We have that $f(0)=\cos{1}$

We can see that $f$ is differentiable on all $\mathbb{R}$ as a composition of differentiable functions.

So your limit  is the derivative of $f$ at $x_0=0$ namely $f'(0)$

Thus $f'(x)=\frac{d(\cos{(1+\ln{(x^2+1)})})}{dx}=-\sin{(1+\ln{(x^2+1)})})(\frac{2x}{x^2+1})$ and $f'(0)=0$

Thus the limit is $0$

Comment: +1 for your answer because it exactly captures what OP intends to know. However I don't prefer this technique unless such limit problem is asked in a time bound objective type test (where time is premium). It is not too difficult to evaluate the limit directly and one can avoid the theorems based on derivatives.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  thanks..Neither do i ..but the O.P demanded an explanation of the relation in his posted picture..Indeed there are plenty ways to evaluate the limit. (except the L'hospital rule of course which i believe leads us to nowhere in this case)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Three applications of the formula in yellow give
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\left(1+\ln\left(1+x^2\right)\right)-\cos(1)}{x}\\
&=\underbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\left(1+\ln\left(1+x^2\right)\right)-\cos(1)}{\ln\left(1+x^2\right)-0}}_{\substack{h(u)=\cos(1+u)\\u=\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}}\,\underbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2\right)-0}{x^2-0\vphantom{\left(x^2\right)}}}_{\substack{h(u)=\ln\left(1+u\right)\\u=x^2}}\,\underbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-0}{x-0\vphantom{\left(x^2\right)}}}_{\substack{h(u)=u^2\\u=x}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This should be considered as a comment which is too long to fit in comment box.

---

The technique given in your question is about observing that the limit is of the form $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)} {x-a} $$ for a suitable $f$ and $a$ and then you can simply evaluate it as $f'(a) $. The technique is quite common (can be seen in some answers on this website also) but there are certain fine points to note when using this technique:

- It takes some amount of experience to figure out the function $f$ but this part of the technique is not difficult.
- It works only when the function $f$ is elementary or is such that the formula for derivative $f'(x) $ can be given easily by using rules of differentiation.
- And finally the above mentioned formula for $f'(x) $ also works for $x=a$. This is the key assumption which amouts to continuity of the derivative $f'$ at $a$.

Unless one is aware of the above limitations it is best to avoid this technique. You may have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1780816/72031) to a related question for some more discussion on this.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh...do you have some time for a discussion in the chat?I want to ask you some things.Thanks in advance

Comment: @MariosGretsas: yes we can  discuss things. Let me know which chat room.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh..i don't know how to move the discussion to chat here..

Comment: @MariosGretsas : visit this link https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65254/for-discussion-with-marios-grestas